# I can send email by pasting file in mailroot/pickup folder but not from asp.net c# code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtp

I have set up a VPS with SMTP server. I use a txt file format of

```
From: noreply@domail.com
To: user@domain.com
Subject: testing

This is the test message body
```

and email sent successfully. But when I want to send email form my code with the following settings it does not send any email.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>      
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreply@domail.com">
        <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

here is my c# code:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                var smtp = new SmtpClient();

                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("noreply@domail.com");
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("user@domain.com"));
                mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
                mailMessage.Body = "test body";
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;                                                                            
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for myYahooID@yahoo.com

Comment: Sounds more like a mail server configuration issue, rather than your code - i.e. the SMTP server you're connecting to isn't configured to allow relaying of email (per the error message)

Answer (score 0):

It was solved.
I change

```
<network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
```

to

```
<network host="ServerIp" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
```

Also I grant access to ServerIp in Relay section of virtual mail server.